# How to annotate class alias in TypeScript for static properties and methods calling?

Tags: typescript, types

Which type will be correct for `self` local variable in the code below?

```js
class SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName {

  static exampleProperty1: number = 1;
  static exampleProperty2: string = 'asdf';

  private someMethod(): void {
    // invalid type
    const self: SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName = SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName;
    console.log(self.exampleProperty1, self.exampleProperty2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the type of the *class* rather than of the *instance* you use `typeof` as a type-query:

```
class X {
  static y: number = 1;
  static z: string = 'hi';
  private someMethod(): void {
    const Class: typeof X = X;
    console.log(Class.y, Class.z);
  }
}
```

You cannot do this in a generic way safely right now (see [Microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) for the details), but you can work around the need for `typeof Y` at all *consumers* of `Y` if the class has an instance property that is of the type of the class:

```
type Class<T> = T extends Object ? T['constructor'] : never;

class Y {
  'constructor': typeof Y;  // Quotes are important
}
type XClass = Class<X>; // Function
type YClass = Class<Y>; // typeof Y;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Typescript type system is **duck-typing**, which means that the right type for your `self` variable is probably to indicate how you intend to use it. In this case it must have the two properties you refer to.

```
class SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName {

  static exampleProperty1: number = 1;
  static exampleProperty2: string = 'asdf';

  private someMethod(): void {
    const self: {exampleProperty1: number,exampleProperty2: string} = SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName;
    console.log(self.exampleProperty1, self.exampleProperty2);
  }
}
```

Let me know whether this works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please tell me which type has `private self`. I suppose, not 'SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName';

Comment: @MarkQ., afraid not... I got `TS2322: Type 'typeof CollapsableAdvantagesDescription' is not assignable to type '{ DETAILS_TEXT_SUBCELL_CSS_CLASS_SELECTOR: string; EXPAND_ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLISECONDS: number; }'.` error.

Comment: Your answer may be in the error message. What about `const self: typeof SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName = SuperHyperMegaExtraVeryPrettyLongClassName;`?